# ¿Como puedo centrar la ventana del modo imagen en imagen (PiP mode)

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-imageview

estoy trabajando un proyecto en android studio con dos lenguajes java y kotlin sobre mostrar una vista en mi aplicación que muestre contenido como video.

Quisiera centrar una instancia del modo imagen en imagen o conocido comúnmente picture and picture mode, actualmente cuando inicio la instancia esta se crea en el extremo inferior derecho pero quisiera tener mayor control sobre donde aparece por ejemplo quiero que cuando aparezca la instancia aparezca en la parte central de la pantalla del dispositivo.

lo que eh intentado por medio del layout es intentar centrarlo con  **android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"** pero no funcionó sigue apareciendo en el extremo inferior derecho.

Otra opción que eh intentado es agregar **android:layout_centerInParent="true"** pero nada y por ultimo intente modificar directamente el código con las constantes de gravity de la api de android pero nada...

y por ultimo me situé en el android manifest añadiendo la etiqueta

**android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"**

Este es el código que actualmente estoy trabajando:

VideoPL.java

```
    package com.sim.lyxx;

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.ActivityOptions
import android.app.PictureInPictureParams
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.PixelFormat
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Rational
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView
import com.sim.lyxx.databinding.CustomToastBinding

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
class VideoPL : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: CustomToastBinding
    private var mExoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null
    private var isPipMode: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = CustomToastBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        hideSystemUI()

        // Inicializa ExoPlayer y comienza la reproducción
        initializeExoPlayer()

        // Entra en modo PIP al iniciar la actividad
        createPIPMode()

        // Configura el listener para la visibilidad del controlador
        binding.exoPlayer.setControllerVisibilityListener { visibility ->
            val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_customPlayBackControlView)
            if (layout.tag != "IN_ANIMATION") {
                when (visibility) {
                    View.GONE -> {
                        layout.tag = "IN_ANIMATION"
                        binding.exoPlayer.showController()
                        layout.animate().alpha(0F).setDuration(450L)
                            .withEndAction({
                                binding.exoPlayer.hideController()
                                layout.tag = ""
                            }).start()
                    }
                    View.VISIBLE -> {
                        layout.animate().alpha(1F).setDuration(450L).start()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // Bloquea los eventos táctiles solo cuando estás en modo Picture-in-Picture
        if (isInPictureInPictureMode) {
            // Retorna true para consumir los eventos táctiles y evitar que se propaguen a otras vistas
            return true
        }

        // Continúa con el comportamiento predeterminado cuando no estás en modo Picture-in-Picture
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    }

    private fun hideSystemUI() {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
            (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE)
    }

    private fun initializeExoPlayer() {
        mExoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(applicationContext).build()
        binding.exoPlayer.player = mExoPlayer
        binding.exoPlayer.useController = false
        binding.exoPlayer.hideController()
        binding.exoPlayer.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL

        val mediaItem: MediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4")
        mExoPlayer!!.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        mExoPlayer!!.prepare()
        mExoPlayer!!.play()


    }

    override fun onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode: Boolean) {
        super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode)
        if (!isInPictureInPictureMode) {
            // Restaura configuración después de salir del modo PiP
            binding.exoPlayer.useController = false
            binding.exoPlayer.hideController()

        }
    }

    private fun createPIPMode() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            val pictureInPictureParams = PictureInPictureParams.Builder()

                .build()

            enterPictureInPictureMode(pictureInPictureParams)
        }
    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (isPipMode) {
            createPIPMode()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun cancelExecution(activity: Activity) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && activity.isInPictureInPictureMode) {
                val params = PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
                    .setAspectRatio(Rational(16, 9))
                    .build()
                activity.setPictureInPictureParams(params)
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Actividad VideoPL cerrada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                if (activity is MainActivity) {
                    // Cierra la actividad actual y reinicia la aplicación
                    val intent = Intent(activity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    activity.startActivity(intent)
                    activity.finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:gravity="top|start|center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/exoPlayer"
        app:show_timeout="@null"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/layout_custom_exo_player_pip"
        android:gravity="top|start|center"
        app:use_controller="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_toast_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="32sp"

        android:text="View"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

android_manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".VideoPL"
        android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >

        <layout
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:defaultHeight="100dp"
            android:defaultWidth="100dp"
            android:minHeight="150dp"
            android:minWidth="300dp"
            />
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
```